# How to do sum in Loop

Tags: python, loops, sum

I have a exercise ,Input data will contain the total count of pairs to process in the first line.
The following lines will contain pairs themselves - one pair at each line.
Answer should contain the results separated by spaces.
My code:

```
    n = int(raw_input())
    sum = 0

    for i in range(n):
        y = raw_input().split(" ")
        for i in y:
            sum = sum + int(i)


    print sum
```

With my code , I come the Sum together, but I will that the results to come separated by spaces . Thanks for yours help .

Comment: If you want to print the partial sums, move both the `sum = 0` and the `print` inside the outer loop.

Comment: The code is messed up. Why are two loops having the same iternator name (i). Try changing the iterator in the second loop from i to j.

Comment: @SuryaTejaKarra That's not the problem. `i` is not used in the outer loop, so it being redefined in the inner does not matter (but is certainly bad practice).

Comment: @tobias_k , can you please tell to me how to do with a Exemple , I am very new in Python...

Comment: what is goal? print the sum of each pair number?

Comment: yes , but all in a Line and separated by spaces , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your current code what you get is the total sum of all the given numbers, to get the sum per line you need to initialize your counter in the outer loop, and then print it, and as you want to print all it in the same line there are several ways to do it, like save it in a list or telling [print](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) that don't print a new, line which is done by adding a `,` at the end like `print x,` with that in mind then the changes needed are

```
n = int(raw_input())
for i in range(n):
    pairs = raw_input().split() #by default split use spaces 
    pair_sum = 0
    for p in pairs:
        pair_sum += int(p) # a += b is the same as a = a + b
    print pair_sum, 

 print ""  # to print a new line so any future print is not done in the same line as the previous one
```

that was the version with print per line, next is the version using list

```
n = int(raw_input())
resul_per_line = []
for i in range(n):
    pairs = raw_input().split() #by default split use spaces 
    pair_sum = 0
    for p in pairs:
        pair_sum += int(p) # a += b is the same as a = a + b
    resul_per_line.append( str(pair_sum) ) #conver each number to a string to use with join bellow

 print " ".join(resul_per_line)
```

with either of the above let said for example that the input data is

```
3
1 2
40 50
600 700
```

then the result would be

```
3 90 1300
```

---

some parts of the above code can be simplify by using [built in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) functions like [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum), for example this part

```
    pair_sum = 0
    for p in pairs:
        pair_sum += int(p)
```

can become

```
    pair_sum = sum( map(int,pairs) )
```

Comment: Thanks , that is what i want .

Answer (score 0):

Uh oh, it looks like you're reusing the same variable `i` in the inner loop as the outer loop -- this is bad practice and can lead to bugs down the road.

What you're doing currently is adding both elements in each pair to sum and then printing that at the end, you can fix this in two different ways.

1. You can sum each pair, convert the sum to a string, and then concatenate that with your the rest of the sums as strings, or
2. You can print the sum of each pair immediately after summing them with `print sum,` which will print the number without the newline so that you can print all the results on a single line.

Comment: Can you give me a Exemple , I am new in Python , thnks

Comment: @iratxe For the former or the latter? If we do the latter, you'll want to move `sum = 0` to right before the inner for loop and add a `print sum,` after the the inner loop.